# GNUstep And GTK

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, gtk

I'm learning Objective-C using GNUstep, because I don't have a Mac and the GNUstep GUI applications have that Window Maker style, but it's possible to develop this GUI applications using GTK? Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you want to know if there is a GTK theme for GNUstep?

Comment: If there is a GTK theme or a way to develop with GTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GTK theme for GNUstep in development right now, which should make GNUstep apps a better fit in a GNOME desktop.

Screenshots:

http://stashbox.org/693247/Bildschirmfoto.png
http://stashbox.org/693249/Bildschirmfoto-1.png
http://stashbox.org/705472/Bildschirmfoto.png

More info:

http://heronsperch.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-theming-capabilities.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Themes/NesedahGTK-41743.shtml) is a GTK+ version of the GNUStep "Nesedah" theme, that might be what you're after. I had a look at http://art.gnome.org/themes/gtk2 but didn't find anything more obvious.